# Proof that $P(A \cup B \cup C)=P(A)+P(A^{c} \cap B)+P(A^{c} \cap B^{c} \cap C)$

Tags: probability

I want to show that $P(A \cup B \cup C)=P(A)+P(A^{c} \cap B)+P(A^{c} \cap B^{c} \cap C)$, so note that

\begin{align*}
  P(A \cup (B \cup C)) &= P(A)+P(B \cup C)- P(A \cap (B \cup C))\\
  &= P(A)+P(B \cup C)-P((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)) \\
  &= P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap C) +P(A \cap B \cap C)\\
  &=P(A)+ P(B \cap A^{c})+P(C \cap A^{c})+P(A \cap B \cap C) 
\end{align*}

Remember that $B=(B \cap A^{c}) \cup (B \cap B)$

But of course, from here it is not easy to conclude the result I think, any way to reach the requested? I appreciate it!

Comment: If you see "$P(X) = P(Y) + P(Z) + P(W)$", a natural thought to have is "boy, I hope that $X$ is the disjoint union of $Y$, $Z$, and $W$!". Is this the case here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for *any* events $X$ and $Y$, we can prove $\mathsf P(X\cup Y)=\mathsf P(X)+\mathsf P(X^\complement\cup Y)$ because  *you can show* that $X\cup Y = X\cup (X^\complement\cap Y)$  and the sets $X$ and $X^\complement\cap Y$ are disjoint.

Once *you have shown these things*, you use:$$\begin{align}A\cup B\cup C & = A\cup (A^\complement\cap (B\cup C))\\ & = A\cup (A^\complement\cap(B\cup(B^\complement\cap C)))  \\ &= A\cup(A^\complement\cap B)\cup(A^\complement\cap B^\complement\cap C)\end{align}$$